# Trigger firing when it shouldn't

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER SalaryCannotDecrease ON Employees
AFTER UPDATE
AS
IF EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM inserted, deleted
            WHERE inserted.Salary < deleted.Salary
            )
BEGIN
    RAISERROR 30002 'You cannot decrease salary';
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    RETURN
END;
```

And this trigger is firing when I try to:

```
UPDATE Employees
SET Salary = Salary * 1.05
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just looking at your query [this might show](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/231f1/2) what is partially wrong. You need to join the inserted and deleted within your trigger to properly pull valid data. Once you do that I think it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, just a little terminology thing: you do want your trigger to *fire*, since you are updating `Employees`; you just don't want the `IF` statement's condition to be satisfied.

---

Now on to the problem. When you list tables in a `FROM` clause like this:

```
FROM inserted, deleted
```

you are actually creating a `CROSS JOIN` between the tables. So this `SELECT` subquery will be looking at **every combination** of `inserted` and `deleted` rows, and looking for *any* instance where *some* `inserted.Salary` is less than *some other* `deleted.Salary`.

So if your salaries were

```
100
200
300
```

to start with, your `UPDATE` would try and change them to

```
105
210
315
```

and the combinations considered in the subquery would be:

```
Is 105 < 100? No
Is 210 < 100? No
Is 315 < 100? No
Is 105 < 200? Yes
Is 210 < 200? No
Is 315 < 200? No
Is 105 < 300? Yes
Is 210 < 300? Yes
Is 315 < 300? No
```

Hence the `IF` condition is met, and the `ROLLBACK` takes place.

To fix it, be sure to only compare `inserted.Salary` to `deleted.Salary` **for the same employee**, by specifying the `Employees` primary key (here I asssume `Id`) in an explicit `JOIN`:

```
FROM inserted INNER JOIN deleted ON inserted.Id = deleted.Id
```

---

The two general points are:

- Don't write `FROM table1, table2` in queries - always be explicit about the kind of join you want
- When writing triggers, always bear in mind that `inserted` / `deleted` can have more than one record in them

Answer (score 5):

Join `Employees` table's unique ID with inserted in trigger.

```
--- Employees table 
CREATE TABLE Employees
( EmpID INT,  --- unique id for employee
  Salary INT
)

--- Dummy data insertion
INSERT INTO Employees
SELECT 11001,5000
UNION ALL 
SELECT 10003,6500
UNION ALL 
SELECT 10004,6900
UNION
SELECT 10006,300


-- Salary Trigger 
CREATE TRIGGER SalaryCannotDecrease ON Employees
AFTER UPDATE
AS
IF EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM inserted INNER JOIN deleted ON inserted.empid=deleted.empid
            WHERE inserted.Salary < deleted.Salary
            )
BEGIN
    RAISERROR 30002 'You cannot decrease salary';
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    RETURN
END;


-- Update Statement
UPDATE Employees
SET Salary = Salary * 1.05
WHERE empid=10006


--- Verification 
SELECT * FROM Employees
```

Comment: Joining with the `inserted` table on identical `ID` will usually be faster than joining with the `employees` table, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Twinkles,I cross checked yes by joining 'inserted' with 'deleted' Duration, reads and CPU cost is always better. I modified answer